# Is there a way to control Page size of Page list Component like Search Results in SXA

Tags: sxa, content-search

In SXA Search, I observed that we can control search results display using Page Size and Page Selector components together. But, I want to control page list component also like Search by displaying Pagination and Page Size. I did not find any SXA Page Size Component associated with Page List. Seems it is working only for Search with Page Selector. Kindly let me know if there is any way to make this configurable

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Then only rendering you can associate with `Page List` is `Pagination`. There is not "Page Size" for `Page List` and as you correctly noticed then only place to control `Page List` page size is the field in the Control Properties dialogue.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dawid for the response. I have updated the question with the screenshot as per my requirement. Kindly let me know any customization possible.

Comment: Like I wrote above - no, such customization is not possible unless you wrote it.